# How to configure devd on FreeBSD to run a program whenever a USB keyboard is attached?

Tags: xorg, usb, freebsd, keyboard

Whenever I reattach a USB keyboard to my FreeBSD desktop, my keyboard settings are not reapplied to my newly attached keyboard (`setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` in particular).

I would like to run `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` (or perhaps something more like `su - username -c 'DISPLAY=:0 setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps'`) whenever I attach a USB keyboard.

### What I've tried

#### xorg.conf

I've tried to use Xorg configuration files to achieve what I want to I added the following contents to `/usr/local/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-input.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier              "Keyboard Defaults"
        MatchIsKeyboard         "yes"
        Option                  "XkbLayout" "pl"
        Option                  "XkbOption" "ctrl:nocaps"
EndSection
```

Unfortunately, if I unplug and plug the USB keyboard back again when the Xorg environment is already running, the Caps Lock on the keyboard is back to being a Caps Lock (interestingly, the Caps Lock on the laptop's keyboard is still mapped to Control).

### So...

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use devd (on FreeBSD) or udev (on Linux) for that.

Any X11 client can use the [XInput](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libXi/inputlib.html)/[XInput2](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/inputproto/XI2proto.txt) extension to monitor when X11 input devices like mice or keyboards are added or removed.

No need to run as root from devd/udev, mess up X11 authentication and commit layer violations, cope with devd/udev's limitations, assume that it's a single user machine, etc.

Implementing such a program is trivial; however, as almost everything interesting, **doing it from the shell is messy**.

There's a program called [inputplug](https://github.com/andrewshadura/inputplug) which should allow you to run a shell script when different XInput events happen. However, I've only tried it, I *do not use it myself*, so I cannot vouch for it.

But it does compile (with a little help) on FreeBSD, and it seems to work as expected. YMMV.

```
(as root: pkg install libX11 libXI libxcb)

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/andrewshadura/inputplug
cd inputplug
cc -Wall -include signal.h -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lXi -lxcb -lxcb-xinput inputplug.c -o inputplug

echo 'echo "$@"' > xishow; chmod 755 xishow
./inputplug -c ./xishow

...
XISlaveRemoved 18
XIDeviceDisabled 14 XISlaveKeyboard
XISlaveRemoved 14
XIDeviceDisabled 15 XISlaveKeyboard
XISlaveRemoved 15
XISlaveAdded 12 XIFloatingSlave Telink Wireless Receiver Mouse
XIDeviceEnabled 12 XISlavePointer Telink Wireless Receiver Mouse
XISlaveAdded 13 XIFloatingSlave Telink Wireless Receiver
XIDeviceEnabled 13 XISlaveKeyboard Telink Wireless Receiver
[etc]
```

Comment: inputplug is now available in the FreeBSD ports collection, thanks! https://www.freshports.org/x11/inputplug/

Comment: I've ended up writing a little shell script with inputplug. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Carefully.

It's easy to jam the operation of `devd` with a program that doesn't terminate speedily.
To avoid that, you should probably run a monitor program that connects to `devd`'s output at `/var/run/devd.seqpacket.pipe` like `volmand` does, for example.

## On the other hand …

If you still *do* want to invoke things from `devd` *directly*, then first note that there's almost an existing mechanism for this.
Notice that in `/etc/devd.conf` there's already a rule that runs `/etc/rc.d/syscons` with the `setkeyboard` verb and the device filename.
`setkeyboard` does the sort of thing that you are trying to do, except that it is calling `kbdcontrol` to configure the maps and stuff for the FreeBSD kernel's internal terminal emulator that is used for the virtual terminals.
This is how your mechanism should work, too.

If you decide to, say, add a priority 101 rule that matches `ukbd[0-9]+` in an `/usr/local/etc/devd/mateusz.conf` file, note that you must copy what the existing rule does if you don't want to break USB keyboard usage on your virtual terminals.
`devd` rules are not cumulative; higher priority ones *replace* lower priority ones.
`/dev/ukbd*` are of course your USB keyboard device files.

And yes: a `match` of `cdev` uses regular expressions, not shell wildcards; and `/usr/local/etc/devd/` is the right place for `devd` rulesets that don't come with the operating system.

## On the gripping hand …

Note that *this might not solve your problem*.
`Xorg` in the FreeBSD ports tree has an additional `config/devd` module patched in.
That *also* listens to `devd`'s output pipe, and attempts to dynamically attach and detach things as keyboard and mouse devices come and go.
It *usually* only attaches to the keyboard concentrator device, `/dev/kbdmux0`, and ignores other keyboard devices.
Its decision when to do so is somewhat complex.
None of this is, alas, documented for an end user; not even its existence.

As such, the better way to approach things is not with `devd` rules at all, but with `Xorg` ones.

The `config/devd` module in `Xorg` registers an `InputDevice` for a `devd:kbdmux` keyboard, so you simply need your `Xorg.conf` to set an `Option` for `"XkbOptions"` to `"ctrl:nocaps"` for keyboard class devices.
There's an example of pretty much that in Chapter 5 of the *FreeBSD Handbook*.

## Further reading

- [`devd.conf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devd.conf).  2019-05-31.  *File Formats Manual*.  FreeBSD.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a note on xorg.conf.